# Java ArrayList splitting into two columns

Tags: java, arraylist

The code below is asking how many names you are about to answer, then tells you to type in all the names you have. I want it so that it will print the names into two columns so that the names are paired together.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("How many names would you like to enter?");
int n = scan.nextInt(); //Ensures you get an integer
System.out.println("Enter the " + n + " names: ");
int N=n+1;
String[] names = new String[N];

//Store the names in an array
for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++){
    names[i] = scan.nextLine();
}

//Prints the names in a list
List<String> AllNames;
AllNames = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(names));
Random rand = new Random();
Collections.shuffle(AllNames, rand);
System.out.println(AllNames);  

}}
```

Comment: To me, your question was unclear. Please specify what you want, and what have you tried...

Comment: *I want it so that it will print the names into two columns so that the names are paired together.* So that which names are paired together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
String[] names = {"pete", "ryan", "bob", "cynthia", "ulga", "sarah", "madison"};

for(int i = 0; i < names.length; i = i + 2)
{
    System.out.print(names[i]);
    if(i + 1 < names.length)
    {
        System.out.print("\t" + names[i + 1]);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Output

```
pete    ryan
bob     cynthia
ulga    sarah
madison
```

Output 2

```
String[] names = {"pete", "ryan", "bob", "cynthia"};
```

Generates the following

```
pete    ryan
bob     cynthia
```

Comment: I need a scanner to put names in here because each time the program is ran, it could have different names

Comment: i know, just take the for loop logic and apply it to your Arraylist called AllNames

Comment: So the only problem I have now within the code is that it prints out a blank space. In the results, if I put 4 names in, it prints 3 of them with a blank space included.

Comment: i just tested it and with four names it gives the correct output. are you sure the data in you have in the arraylist is correct and complete? @JamesD.E.Smith

Answer (score 0):

@RAZ_Muh_Taz
This is what I have so far:

```
`Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("How many names would you like to enter?");
    int n= scan.nextInt(); //Ensures you take an integer
    System.out.println("Enter the " + n + " names: ");                                               
    String[] names = new String[n];
//    Store the names in an array
    for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i=i+1){
        names[i] = scan.nextLine();}
        List<String> AllNames;
// Prints the names in a list
        AllNames = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(names));
        for(int i = 0; i < names.length; i = i + 2) {
            System.out.print(names[i]);
            if(i + 1 < names.length)
            {
        System.out.print(" " +"&"+ " " + names[i + 1] );
        }
    System.out.println();
    }
        Random rand = new Random();
        Collections.shuffle(AllNames, rand);
        scan.close();
}}`
```

The output I always get is:

```
` & a
b & c`
```